# Changing a model without altering the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a model being used to populate a database

```
public class Account
{
    public int NumberOfPayPeriods { get { return 24; } }
    public decimal YearAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal PlanTotal
    {
        get { return NumberOfPayPeriods*YearAmount; }
    }
}
```

The `NumberOfPayPeriods` attribute I need to change from just a `get` to a `get; set;`

However, when I change this, I get an `EntityCommandExecutionException` (invalid column name). I assume this is because it is trying to map this to the database where there previously existed no such column (as it was only a get).

Is there any way I can change this to a get;set; without having to delete the table? There's a lot of important data on there that cannot be lost or re-created.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237822/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-a-table-schema-upgrade-and-have-it-map-to-an-ef-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `[NotMapped]` attribute over the property you don't want stored.

```
public class Account
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int NumberOfPayPeriods { get { return 24; } set { ... } }
    public decimal YearAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal PlanTotal
    {
        get { return NumberOfPayPeriods*YearAmount; }
    }
}
```